# HCL Notes view not showing column headings

Tags: hcl-notes

I have uninstalled a Notes client and Designer 10.0.1 and then installed 12.0.2 64 bit.

In an application database, when opening some (but not all) views in either the client or Designer, the column headers are not displayed. Instead there a "Sort by" link in the top right corner that lists the columns that have the "Click on column heading to sort" property set. For example :-

[image]

[image]

What's causing this to appear like this? I can't see any difference in view or column properties between views that appear like this and views that appear "normally" with column headings showing?

If I uninstall 12.0.2 and reinstall 10.0.1 everything returns to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With assistance from HCL, we discovered this appears to be a corruption in some views. By editing the view DXL (which can be as simple as adding a space, immediately removing it and saving) then the view reverts to "normal".